# Two different ways of passing an array by reference. Which one is more correct?

Tags: c, arrays, function, reference, malloc

I know two ways to pass an array by reference to a function which modifies the array. I just wanted to know which way is more accurate or faster if I have large arrays?

First Example:

Here I pass the array straight forward and manipulate it in the function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void changeArray(int* vec, int sizeArray)
{
     for(int i=0; i<sizeArray; i++)
     {
          vec[i] = vec[i] + 1000;
     }
}

int main()
{
     int n = 10;
     int*vec = NULL;
     vec = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

     printf("Before\n");
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
          vec[i] = i+1;
          printf("%d ", vec[i]);
     }

     changeArray(vec,n);

     printf("\nAfter\n");
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
          printf("%d ", vec[i]);
     }
     printf("\n");

free(vec);
return 0;
}
```

Seconds Example:

In this example I pass the address of my array. Do I send here a pointer to the function? The `changeArray()` functions looks more complicated. Is this just a long way round for the same result?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void changeArray(int** vec, int sizeArray)
{
     for(int i=0; i<sizeArray; i++)
     {
          (*vec)[i] = (*vec)[i] + 1000;
     }
}

int main()
{
     int n = 10;
     int*vec = NULL;
     vec = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

     printf("Before\n");
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
          vec[i] = i+1;
          printf("%d -> ", vec[i]);
     }

     changeArray(&vec,n);

     printf("\nAfter\n");
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
          printf("%d -> ", vec[i]);
     }
     printf("\n");

free(vec);
return 0;
}
```

I am new to programming. So maybe this question is not a good one.

Answer (score 3):

> I just wanted to know which way is more accurate or faster if I have large arrays?

The first method is most correct and can never be slower than the second method.

> In this example I pass the address of my array.

No, you pass the address of a pointer to the first element in the array.

> Is this just a long way round for the same result?

Yes, that function is needlessly complicated and you gain nothing from it. Use the first version.